# Cosa significa "cimosa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il contesto* di Leonardo Sciascia ho letto (il grassetto è mio):

> Il lampo di tentazione a riprendere l'ascensore, a tornare dal presidente, fu appunto un lampo che subito si spense nel ricordo, piuttosto cinico data la circostanza, di Innocenzo quando punta il revolver contro il professore  schopenhaueriano (G.K. Chesterton, *Manalive*): "Non lo farei per il primo venuto, ma voi ed io siamo diventati così amici!". Diretta al presidente, naturalmente: cui forse in quel momento il revolver di Cres stava per saldare il conto. La frase, visivamente ripetendosi in bel corsivo, fece da **cimosa** alle riflessioni che andava svolgendo; e stava svanendo in ritmo, in musica ("non-lo-fa-rei-per-il-pri-mo-ve-nu-to", sul motivo di una canzonetta balneare; e poi "ma poi ed io - siamo diventati così amici!" a frase larga, pucciniana, piglio e timbro baritonale), quando si accorse che già da un pezzo era sull'autobus; ...

Ho cercato il vocabolo "cimosa" nei dizionari, comunque non riesco a capire cosa significhi in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A orecchio direi che si riferisca al cancellino (una striscia di pezza grigia spessa, arrotolata strettamente in modo da formare un tozzo cilindro, utilizzata per cancellare le scritte da una lavagna).

Qui, metaforicamente, quella frase “cancellerebbe”, farebbe sbiadire e sparire progressivamente, tutte le altre riflessioni.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, la cimosa è il bordo delle stoffe cucite. Quindi nel tuo contesto significa che il modo in cui lei parlava in qualche modo impreziosiva e rendeva più solido il suo discorso!

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cimossa

Comment: No, si tratta certamente del cancellino che è chiamato *cimosa* almeno in alcune aree del centro Italia (e.g. in Toscana).

Comment: @DenisNardin Non sono per niente d'accordo. Anzi, questa interpretazione non è da escludere.